Why does the QGIS "age" function return different results as the arcade "datediff" function in ArcGIS Pro?
In my current project, I am required to convert QGIS-Layers into an ESRI Environment.
The QGIS Layers are using a rule base symbology which calculates the age in months using the current date and the "datum" field in the table.
The following simple example shows how the results differ from MSSQL or Arcade
"Age" function within the Symbology Rule for QGIS
month(age( $now, "datum" ))

"AgeDiff" function for ArcGIS Pro in Arcade
DateDiff(Now(),$feature.datum,'month')

The results are displayed below:

Can anyone explain why there is a difference?
Test data can be downloaded here:
URL:        https://cloud.heidekreis.de/index.php/s/MeYB5P5CwFfzFy3
Password:    Qgis_test1

Do they calculate the same interval in a smaller unit (e.g. days)? Then it might be rounding. Which values are correct?

Unfortunately for me, the QGIS Values are the ones which need to be reproduced as these are from the original project which I have to convert.

Looks like rounding; the ones that are highlighted all have "datum" values of <15 in the days, the others are >16, suggesting an inflection at the middle of the month. Would it perhaps be better to take the age of something expressed in months as being from the the first day of the "datum" month to $now? Or perhaps better to describe your period in number of days rather than months, to match the actual precsion of your data?

in QGIS, age returns an interval. From there, the month function assumes 1 month=30 days, so month(age('2024/12/31','2024/01/01')) returns 12.1666 months (12.166..*30days/m=365 days/y), and as others have pointed you are then rounding this value, up or down.
